# Download Jupyter Notebook as .html File with Image Importing Code Excluded (Not Shown)

Tags: python, html, download, jupyter-notebook

I have the following output on my local Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

I want to "Download As" this Jupyter Notebook as a .html file.  But when I open the html file I only want to see the image and not the block of code in `In [6]`.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `markdown` in Jupyter Notebook to render your image file.

[image]

You can change your shell from `code` to `markdown` and run this to get image.

```
![Test](test.png)
```

[image]

If image file is in another folder, you can do the following:

```
![<caption>](folder/image_filename.png)
```

Comment: I am aware of this method.  The problem is when I include images via markdown and then download Jupyter Notebook as HTML file, the images do not render on the HTML file

Comment: You can also use `embedded HTML` option from `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions` . More details are [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: I actually did install the extension and selected the checkbox for embed.  But my local instance of Jupyter Notebook does not give me the embedded HTML option after I click on Download As ... any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Julyter's Insert Image functionality and it'll work.

- Markdown a cell.
- Edit > Insert Image